For which integers $m$ does an infinite string of characters $S = c_{1} \cdot c_{2} \cdot c_{3} \cdot c_{4} \cdot c_{5} \ldots$ exist
Question:
For which integers $m$ does an infinite string of characters
$$S = c_{1} \cdot c_{2} \cdot c_{3} \cdot c_{4} \cdot c_{5} \ldots$$
exist such that for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ there are exactly $m \cdot n$ distinct substrings of $S$ with length $n$? (A substring is a finite subsequence of consecutive characters.)
Bonus:
Does an infinite string $S$ exist such that there are exactly $p_{n}$ distinct substrings of $S$ with length $n$? $p_{n}$ is the $n$th prime.
My attempt: I propose that for $m = 2$, such an infinite string $S$ exists. Consider the string constructed by alternating two characters, say '0' and '1', infinitely: $S = 0101010101\ldots$. It's evident that for any positive integer $n$, there are exactly $2n$ distinct substrings of length $n$ in $S$, as each substring can be uniquely identified by its starting position.
As for the bonus question, I conjecture that no such infinite string $S$ exists. The number of distinct substrings of length $n$ in $S$ corresponds to the number of ways we can choose a substring of length $n$ from $S$. However, the prime number of substrings for each length $n$ imposes restrictions on the length of $S$ and its repetitiveness.
I am very interested in bonus part

Some similarities with (finite !) De Bruijn sequences.

Perhaps I am misunderstanding something, but aren't there only $2$ distinct substrings of length $n$ in $S$ for any $n$? Namely, the one starting with $0$ and the one starting with $1$?

Interesting question! As Haran says, your attempt is incorrect; $S$ only has $2$ distinct substrings of a fixed length, and more generally any periodic string of period $p$ can have at most $p$ distinct substrings of a fixed length.
So we need to consider strings that are not periodic. Here is essentially the simplest example I can think of: consider the string
$$S = 101001000100001000001 \dots $$
where we alternate between $1$ and $0$ but each time increment the number of $0$s by one. A substring of this string is uniquely determined by the position of the first two $1$s in it, if any. We can count the substrings of length $n$ by breaking up into cases:

No $1$s: there is a unique such substring once we go sufficiently far to the right.
One $1$: there are $n$ such substrings once we go sufficiently far to the right.
Two or more $1$s: suppose the first $1$ occurs after $k$ zeroes. Then the next $1$ must occur after $k+1$ or more zeroes, and all such possibilities occur, uniquely. A value of $k$ can occur iff $2k+3 \le n$, and each value of $k$ leads to possibilities $k+j, j \ge 1$ for the number of zeroes between the first two $1$s satisfying $2k+2+j \le n$, so the number of possible values for $j$ is $n-2k-2$. This gives $\sum_{2k+3 \le n} (n-2k-2)$ substrings, which I am too lazy to sum right now but which is of course some quadratic polynomial in $n$.

So we get a quadratic polynomial for the count of substrings of length $n$. In general it would be interesting to say something about which functions $s_n$ can occur as the count of the number of substrings of length $n$. We can produce more complicated variations of the string $S$ above by changing the length of the runs of consecutive $0$s; maybe someone else can figure out whether that lets us make $s_n$ a linear polynomial.
In the above example most of the substrings only occur finitely many often, and only $n+1$ of them (the substrings with at most one $1$) occur infinitely often. So one could alternatively count the substrings which occur infinitely often, which seem easier to control.
